# rendering DataTable from Json, and modifying one of the columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatable

I am rendering the rows of a DataTable from a Json-File which get loaded from the server.

One of the columns, contains a link of logos (images), but that link, should not be rendered as plain text, instead of that, as the logo directely.

How could I do that?

Here is my code to render the DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#osPartner').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "test2.json",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "pId" },
            { "data": "sName" },
            { "data": "lgName" },
            { "data": "logo" },
            { "data": "inc" },
            { "data": "details.teaserImage2" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

All the data is loaded but the the "logo" column are links. How could I display the images, that are on that link, instead of the link (as text)? Is there a possibility to modify that column, and surround the link with html code, like:

```
<img src="logo_url_here_that_i_become_from_jsom" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px">
```

or

```
 logo = "<img src='"+ logo + "' alt='Mountain View' style='width:304px'>"
```

Here is how my json-file looks like:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "sName": "hjp",
        "lgName": "Hi Ju Pi",
        "pId": "lap34208",
        "feat": false,
        "logo": "https://www.link-here.de/images/image1.png",
        "details": {
              "teaserImage": "https://link-here.de/mg/dsa/dev/img/image1.png",
               "teaserImage2": "https://link-here.de/mg/dsa/dev/img/image1.png"
        }
        },
        {
        "sName": "hjp2",
        "lgName": "Hi Ju Pi22",
        "pId": "ldfsdf38",
        "feat": false,
        "logo": "https://www.link2-here.de/images/image2.png",
        "details": {
              "teaserImage": "https://another-link-here.de/mg/dsa/dev/img/picture1.png",
               "teaserImage2": "https://another-link-here.de/mg/dsa/dev/img/pic2.png"
        }}
    }]
```

}

Comment: what is the extension of your image?? is this `logo_url_here_that_i_become_from_jsom` right url?

Comment: there should be the url of the logo, that i am becomming in the DataTable in the 4th column "logo" as you can see in the ajax/js code. Because now, i am becomming the logo-url as plain text there, but I want to display the logo-image, which is at that link

Comment: How does the JSON look like? Something indicates that the "log" items contain HTML that could be altered.

Comment: any ideas? it should be not so complicated i think.. i am just stuck on it

Comment: You are using a plugin that generates the table from your JSON ? `DataTable` ?

Comment: yes i am using DataTable 
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `render` method :

```
"columns": [
   { "data": "pId" },
   { "data": "sName" },
   { "data": "lgName" },
   { "data": "logo",
     render : function( data, type, full, meta ) {
       return type == 'display' ? '<img src="'+ data + '"/>' : data
     }
   },
   { "data": "inc" },
   { "data": "feat" }
]
```

You can get all items for the row through the `full` variable (if you want to set a certain `title` or similar for the `<img>`).

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria, yes - messed up the `}` / `]`'s, have corrected the example now.

Comment: and if I want to render the "teaserImage2" as a column as well.. how could I do that? I don't even get it as plain text.. how to access it? I tried with " { "data": "details:teaserImage2" } but I couldn't.. but if I could it would be the same problem after that, like the first one, that we solved above.. how to render it first of all, and to get it as hrml link not plain text? So 1st problem: Accessing it & 2nd Problem, rendering it as link not plain text
PS: I modified the structure of my json now.. you can see the actual one above

Comment: use `{ data: "details.teaserImage2" ...` dot, not colon, and then a `render` method the same ways as above.